# Plotting ablines onto xyplot with grouped data

Tags: r, plot

I have revenue data grouped by years, and I plotted it using `xyplot` in lattice. I want to plot the OLS line through each group of data. So, I'd like one line for each year (2013, 2014, 2015, and 2016). I reproduced the code below.

Thanks for your help!

```
xyplot(revenue ~ subs, groups = year,
    main="Revenue v. Subscribers, Journals",
    xlab="Subscribers",
    ylab="Revenue",
    col=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    pch=c(0, 1, 2, 5),
    key=list(columns=2, space="right",
    text=list(lab=c("2013","2014","2015","2016")),
    points=list(pch=c(0, 1, 0, 1), col=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
))
```

Comment: Please, add your data.frame using dput() .